# How to assign element of looping array to another in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

...

```
function ar(farray) {
    var array = farray.slice(0, 2);
    for (i = 2; i <= farray.length; i++) {
        if (array[0] < farray[i]) {
            //Here is the problem.Why i can 't just (re)assign value, referencing to another array? 
            //need to be assigned-copied-rewrited!!
            array[0] = farray[i];
        }
    }
    return array[0] + array[1];
}
```

**Create a function that returns the sum of the two lowest positive numbers given an array of minimum 4 integers. No floats or empty arrays will be passed.**

```
function sumTwoSmallestNumbers(numbers) {  
var array=numbers.slice(0,2);
array.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
array[0]=numbers[0];
array[1]=numbers[1];
for (i=2;i<=numbers.length; i++){
if  (numbers[i]<array[0] || numbers[i]<array[1]) {
 if (numbers[i]<array[0]) {
 array[0]=numbers[i];
} else {
array[1]=numbers[i];
     }           
  }
```

**Solved!**

```
//My sorting relies on positions of value in 'array', therefore for every 'for' loop I need prepared positions
 array.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
}
return array[0]+array[1];
};
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: can you please be more specific

Comment: My array doesn't become changed through loop when I return it.

Comment: You are not returning the array. Just do `return array;` instead of that sum, which would be just a number.

Comment: array[0] scope within a function is not global.
use something like this.

`var yourGlobalVariable;
function foo() {
    // ...
}`

Comment: trincot   "Sum of it's changed elements-if to be spesific.."                              Shashi Ow, that is a good idea, I'm gonna try it

Comment: @Shashi are you high ? he is returning value .

Comment: @mahi if I am guessing it right, he wants the same array with new updated values right ?

Comment: @Shashi no, original array must be not modified

Comment: @qazweriopkoilj original array(farray) is not modified .

Comment: @qazweriopkoilj in that case if you are going to need the array throughout your application, global variable might be the choice, unless someone points out a better way!! have you tried assigning it to a global variable ?

Comment: @Shashi These variables use value of parameter of the function, hence there is no point in defining variables before-outside of function. In any case, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

why you need another array ?

```js
function ar(farray) {
    var a = farray[0];
    for (i = 2; i <= farray.length; i++) {
        if (a < farray[i]) 
            a = farray[i];
    }
    return a + farray[1];
}
```

Comment: If to be absolutely specific I'm doing exercises:**Create a function that returns the sum of the two lowest positive numbers given an array of minimum 4 integers. No floats or empty arrays will be passed.**           function sumTwoSmallestNumbers(numbers) {  
var array=numbers.slice(0,2);
array.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
var a1=numbers[0];
var a2=numbers[1];
for (i=2;i<=numbers; i++){
if  (numbers[i]<a1 || numbers[i]<a2) {
 if (numbers[i]<a1) {
 a1=numbers[i];
} else {
a2=numbers[i];
     }           
  }
}
return a1+a2;
};

Comment: Ok, but I needed not to solve this exercise, but to learn the conception, because this is not the first time my code does not work.

Comment: code not working!!, welcome to the world of programming!! :D Cheers!!